# Editing colors of Shield Point Symbol in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology

I have been transitioning from ArcMap 10.6 to ArcGIS Pro 2.3. I believe that I have a handle on many of the changes that I need. At least I've been able to find documentation that helps. However, I have a fiddly bit that I've been unable to solve.

I am trying to change the colors of the point symbol, 'Shield 1'. It comes as a dark Red and Blue, whereas my client would greatly prefer a pastel color scheme. When one selects the 'color' option, the main color (the bottom part of the shield) can be changed. I have not been able to find a way to change the top part of the shield, (the pointy bit).

Is this possible?

[image: A zoomed in version of the shield that needs editing.]

[image: A focus on which part of the Label Class is important]

Answer (score 3):

At first, make a point **symbol**. Left-Click on your symbol, which will guide you to "format point symbol". Then you can select layer and modify each layer separately.

[image]

[image]

There is a missing step to use the custom symbol as a label. Once you are happy with your new symbol, save it to style and it will appear in your symbols when you update the properties of your label.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! However, it looks to me as though you've created a newly colored _marker_, whereas I'm looking to edit the display of the _label_. I get there by right clicking the layer, selecting 'label properties', symbol, and then callout. This provides a label with the highway number within the shield.